# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created, selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a problem, every, single, ***TIME***
Basically this is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe"
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--no-default-browser-check")
options.add_argument("--no-first-run")
options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

and the error is

`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created`

I used Pycharm and tried to use VS code with python 3.4 and 3.7 and 3.8.3
plz help me I'm getting tired of this.

Full error Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/um/PycharmProjects/Selenium/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\um\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\um\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\um\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\um\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\um\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.83)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not

> unable to send message to renderer

as you mentioned. According to the stack trace you posted the problem in the line 6

> `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="chromedriver.exe", )`

and the problem is:

> `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created`

It seems like you specified an invalid path to the chromedriver and Selenium is unable to initialize the driver and create a session.
You should also [check the version of the chromedriver with the guide](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection).
[Here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.69/) you can download the valid version (I have taken your Chrome version from the stacktrace).

Comment: So a would will start by saying thank you for giving me ur precious time and i have changed my code in the question and same thing happend

Comment: Have you actually seen the Chrome started while your code was being executed?

Answer (score 0):

yes it did start and then close with the error log above, and also i have the correct version